# Automatically migrate traffic to newest google app engine version

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

We are trying to automatically migrate traffic to the latest built version of our production branch of our app in google app engine.  I can't find a good resource after about an hour of investigation on how to do this.  Does anyone know if this is possible and where I can find resources on how to do this?

Comment: You haven't told us what you've tried, but if you always use the same version when you deploy this happens automatically. There is no requirement to change or increment version on subsequent releases (I.e. They are by definition not semver or build versions of your software)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the app/module version in your web.xml file at every build then you need to either assign the new version as the default version or migrate the traffic to the new version. AFAIK both of these actions can only be done manually, from the [Developer Console's Versions Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions).

But if you don't change the app/module version in your web.xml file then the updated code should automatically receive the same traffic as the previous code simply by deployment. At least in the standard GAE environment.

Answer (score 0):

For Python applications it's possible to use `appcfg.py set_default_version <app-directory>` to set the default version to the one specified in `app,yaml`.

I'm assuming that `appcfg.sh set_default_version <app-directory>`, described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appcfg-arguments), does the same thing for Java applications.